# why only column size works but only row size does not works in 2-d array initialisation?

Tags: c, arrays

this works

```
 int a[][2]={
               {2,4},
               {6,8}
            };
```

but this shows error

```
int a[2][]={
              {2,4},
              {6,8}
           };
```

why giving only column size shows no error but giving only row size gives error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, you can omit only the length of first dimension. For 1D array, you can do as

```
int oneD_array[2] = {1,2};
```

or

```
int oneD_array[] = {1,2};
```

In case of 2D array, both of

```
int twoD_array[2][2] = {  {2,4}, {6,8} };
```

and

```
int twoD_array[][2] = {  {2,4}, {6,8} };
```

is valid.
But the above declaration is valid only if the initializer is present. Otherwise it would through error.
The compiler uses length of the initializer to determine how long is the array. But the length of the column can't be determined this way. Without knowing the length of the array, compiler is not able to calculate the address of its corresponding elements. By knowing the length of rows and column, compiler calculate the address of its elements using array equation:

```
address(array) = address(first element) + (row number * columns + column number)*sizeof)type)
```

---

**Detailed look on [array equation](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/append-c.html):**

A 2D array in C is treated as a 1D array whose elements are 1D arrays (the rows).

For example, a `4x3` array of `T` (where `T` is some data type) may be declared by:  `T  mat[4][3]`,  and described by the following scheme:

```
                       +-----+-----+-----+
  mat == mat[0]   ---> | a00 | a01 | a02 |
                       +-----+-----+-----+
                       +-----+-----+-----+
         mat[1]   ---> | a10 | a11 | a12 |
                       +-----+-----+-----+
                       +-----+-----+-----+
         mat[2]   ---> | a20 | a21 | a22 |
                       +-----+-----+-----+
                       +-----+-----+-----+
         mat[3]   ---> | a30 | a31 | a32 |
                       +-----+-----+-----+
```

The array elements are stored in memory row after row, so the array equation for element `mat[m][n]` of type `T` is:

```
address(mat[i][j]) = address(mat[0][0]) + (i * n + j) * size(T)

address(mat[i][j]) = address(mat[0][0]) + 
                     i * n * size(T)    + 
                     j * size(T)

address(mat[i][j]) = address(mat[0][0]) + 
                     i * size(row of T) + 
                     j * size(T)
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has to convert the array into a linear structure (i.e. memory addresses). It does this by multiplying the row number by the width of the column then add the column number you are interested in. You can note that this calculation requires the width (number of columns) needs to be known. The compiler is able to count the number of rows.

So memory address = row number * number of columns + column number you are interested in. Cannot get away from the fact that `number of columns` is a compile time requirement

Comment: Are there smart compilers that can determine num columns from the initializer `{}` syntax? It seems as though it's a simple parsing problem.

Comment: I suppose but I guess it is a good check for n-dimension arrays